# Diodon not working after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, clipboard, clipboard-manager

Diodon does not open any more after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If I start `diodon` from the shell, I see these error message each time I press ctrl-alt-v:

```
(diodon:20112): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Dropping signal AcceleratorActivated 
        of type (uuu) since the type from the expected interface is (uu)
```

That's really sad, since I use this great tool a lot.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
===> diodon --version
Diodon 1.3.0
```

Comment: Have you tried using the version of the stable ppa? https://launchpad.net/~diodon-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://esite.ch/2015/07/using-custom-shortcuts-of-de-as-diodon-hotkey/

You should register the short-cut via desktop environment (not via diodon config)

Go to **System Settings** → **Keboard**, select **Shortcuts** tab and add a new custom shortcut for diodon. Important: You need to click on "deactivated" if you want to asign a new short-cut. Clicking on the name of the shortcut does not work!

This works for Diodon 1.3.0 from Ubuntu 16.04 (ppa version is not needed)